# Ошибка IndentationError: unexpected unindent

Tags: python, flask, pymysql

Сейчас делаю сайт, возникла проблема с базой данных. Используется Mysql и python библиотека PyMySql

Написал небольшой код:

```
import pymysql

#class Database:
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='', db='media')
def register_user(nickname, username, surname , password):
    try:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            sql = "INSERT INTO users (`id`, `password`, `username`, `user_surname`, `nickname`, 
`friends_count`, `subs_count`, `groups_count`, `status`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s)"
            cursor.execute(sql, ('0', password, username, surname, nickname, '0' '0', '0','user' ))
            
    connection.commit()

connection.close
```

При вызове функции через другой файл, выдает следующую ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "app.py", line 1, in <module>
 from core import core
File "C:\Users\0250\Desktop\it\media\core\core.py", line 13
connection.close
^
IndentationError: unexpected unindent
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Где `except:`, соответствующий блоку `try:`?
2. Где скобки у вызова функции `connection.close`?
3. И, наконец, непонятно - а к чему относится вообще этот `connection.close`? Похоже, он у вас выполнится сразу при подключении данного файла, тут же вслед за открытием коннекшена. Это точно то, что вы хотите?